# Disable Charm bar's Touchpad gesture shortcut

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

I'm using an Acer AO722 laptop. **Everytime I slide my finger from the right edge of the touchpad (where the slider is) toward the center** (mostly accidentally), the charmbar pops up and stays on the screen until I manually click on some random spots on the screen.

There's no such option in the Synaptics properties:

[image]

.. nor is there any in the mouse option.

Is there a way to turn this shortcut off?

Comment: Give a try to [skip metro suite](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.103)

Comment: I dont's want to disable the usual shortcut at the corners of the screen, I just want to disable the gesture in my trackpad

Comment: mouse properties? .. Check there. Or check if you have some proprietary drivers like the synaptic touch drivers for instance.

Comment: @Chin there a check box for `charm bar` I think it will only disable it, not all shortcuts?

Comment: @avirk I mean I want to keep the `charm bar` and `all shortcuts associated to it that are on the screen`, I just want to remove `the mouse gesture shortcut the opens it`

Comment: @Gutsygibbon no it's not in either place

Comment: @chin I got it, let's see if I find a way. Well, strnage I have Acer Extensa and this is not a feature there.

Comment: I can't add this answer until I get more reputation. But here it goes:

Make a backup of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\PlugInConfig\Defaults\CustomZones and all sub-keys, then delete it.

Tested under Win8.1 using Synaptics v17.0.15 drivers (Razer not generic).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try installing the latest version of the touchpad driver, available from [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers).

I installed it last night on my laptop, and after restarting, there will be a whole host of new options at the bottom of the list. The option that you are looking to disable is the one that allows you to swipe from off the right edge of the touchpad to the center - that is what is activating the charms.

**Edit:**

The feature you're looking to disable in the Synaptics driver settings is "Enable Edge Swipes". The image below is the settings for the driver version `16.2.21 25Oct12`.

[image: Synaptics settings screenshot]

The the description from the help text:

> **Enable Edge Swipes**
>
> Select the Enable Edge Swipes checkbox to enable a one-finger movement from the edge of the TouchPad in towards the center of the TouchPad:
>
> 1. A swipe from the left edge to the center switches from the currently open application to the previously open application.
> 2. A swipe from the right edge to the center opens or closes the Charms bar.
> 3. A swipe from the the top edge to the center opens or closes the Application Bar.

Comment: you're right, it's described here: http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/windows8 I'm installing the new driver, hope it works

Comment: Well they improved a lots of thing but **Two finger scrolling** bother me a lot. +1 ::)

Answer (score 2):

This is a much better solution. You can use your OEM's touchpad drivers instead. Synaptics' new drivers are flakey.

This works!

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-touchpad-gestures-in-windows-8/