# Windows 8.1 Lenovo notebook non-touchscreen

Tags: windows

My touchpad is set to show charms when I move my finger from right to left, and then my work disappears and the metro screen takes over.  To get back to what I was doing, I have to click the corner.  Can I stop this annoying feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Charm bar's Touchpad gesture shortcut](http://superuser.com/questions/511888/disable-charm-bars-touchpad-gesture-shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Synaptics Touchpad (90% of systems), go to Control Panel > Mouse Properties > Device Settings and click on the Settings button to get a screen similar to what's below. Find the Enable Edge Swipes option and disable it.

[image: Synaptics Touchpad Settings]

If you can't find that option, you may need to update your drivers or download the drivers from [Synaptics website](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers) instead of using the OEM drivers.

#### See also

> [Disable Charm bar's Touchpad gesture shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/511888/disable-charm-bars-touchpad-gesture-shortcut)